# How to make phone call after pressing specific icon on recyclerview?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

I am a beginner Level Android Learner ,using kotlin. I want to call the contact no.(whatever user save their profile) by pressing this marked icon(phone icon). Idk how can I do this properly. I spent much time to find out this solution but I couldn't.  [image: At Image here showing,Data from Firestore]

Here is Adapter Code:

```
class PostAdapter(private var postUser: ArrayList<PostUser>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder>() {

    class PostViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val name: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.patientNameTextView)
        val bloodGroup: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.patientBGTextView)
        val contact: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.patientCNTextView)
        val patientAddress: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.PatientaddressTextView)
        val patientDistrict: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.PatientDistrictTextView)
        val patientAge: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.patientAgeTextView)
        val bloodNeed: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.patientBNTextView)
        val patientType: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.patientTypeTextView)

    }
    fun setFilteredList(postUser: ArrayList<PostUser>){
        this.postUser= postUser
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PostViewHolder {
        val itemView=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.group_donor,parent,false)
        return PostViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PostViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val pUser:PostUser=postUser[position]

        holder.name.text=pUser.name
        holder.patientAge.text=pUser.age
        holder.patientAddress.text=pUser.address
        holder.bloodNeed.text=pUser.bloodBag
        holder.bloodGroup.text=pUser.bloodGroup
        holder.contact.text=pUser.mobile
        holder.patientType.text=pUser.illness
        holder.patientDistrict.text=pUser.district


    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return postUser.size
    }

}
```

The id of this icon is "@+id/callButton".
here is my data class's code:

```
data class PostUser(
    val name:String?=null,
    val age:String?=null,
    val address:String?=null,
    val mobile:String?=null,
    val bloodGroup:String?=null,
    val bloodBag:String?=null,
    val district:String?=null,
    val illness:String?=null
)
```

And finally my Activity Code is here:

```
 private lateinit var userList: ArrayList<com.example.blood.utilities.PostUser>
    private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore
    private lateinit var myAdapter: PostAdapter
    private lateinit var searchView: SearchView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_o_negative)

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.userList)
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        userList = arrayListOf()

        myAdapter = PostAdapter(userList)
        recyclerView.adapter = myAdapter
        Post()
 }

    private fun Post() {
        db.collection("patients")
            .addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {
                override fun onEvent(
                    value: QuerySnapshot?,
                    error: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
                    if(error!=null){
                        Log.e("Firestore Error",error.message.toString())
                        return
                    }
                    for (db : DocumentChange in value?.documentChanges!!){
                        if(db.type== DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                            userList.add(db.document.toObject(com.example.blood.utilities.PostUser::class.java))
                        }
                    }
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }

            })

    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common?hl=en#DialPhone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this permission (In Manifest file )

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Call this method with number in parameter when user clicked that icon.

```
fun dialPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: String) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL).apply {
            data = Uri.parse("tel:$phoneNumber")
        }
        if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
```

You can set onclick listener in onBindViewHolder method or you can also create interface and get click listener in activity.

eg:- In onBindViewHolder ...

```
holder.callIcon.setOnClickListener {
    dialPhoneNumber(pUser.mobile)
  }
```

Comment: ZazhakAllohu Khoiran  brother

Comment: Alhumdolillah :)